# Rspec and environment configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

How can I force Rspec to get config from config/settings/test.yml ?

I use gem "config"

Inside Rspec folder i have rails_helper.rb file with:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
```

When I start

> bundle exec rspec

Rspec persistently try to retrive data from config/settings.yml

Comment: Are you using Config gem or rails_config gem? Share your code which is using config/settings.yml as setting.

Comment: @Manishh that one: https://github.com/railsconfig/config

Comment: Please add your config/application.rb only related code.

Comment: I found a solution. It turned out that the settings.local.yml file overwrites all files in the config/settings/** directory. Because Rspec uses the TEST environment, it was necessary to overwrite the configuration by create new config file config/settings/test.local.yml